# сделать scroll за пределами div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть блок,у которого сделан scroll с помощью

```
     overflow-y:scroll;
     overflow-x:hidden;
```

реально сделать скролл не в div,а снаружи div

Comment: Не надо ломать стандартный гуй, который корректно работает на всех платформах. Можно вытворить странные вещи с помощью падингов наугад и жабоскрипта, но это путь к неприятностям.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильнее всего, в данном случае будет использовать JavaScript библиотеки, которые позволяют создавать кастомный scrollbar, например, [mcustomscrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/).

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".content").mCustomScrollbar();
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.0.6/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.0.8/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" />
<div class="main">
  <div class="content mCustomScrollbar" data-mcs-theme="dark">
    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
    animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
    est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
  </div>
</div>
```

[Пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15u2hbfm/)